# Verify a testing filename in Python using a certain schema

Tags: python, json

I am building a testing framework and have outputs going into folder structures. I would like to verify if these outputs fit a certain schema at the point at which I generate the filename.

Example schema:
`test_<output_type>_<folder_type>_<int>.json`

Example output:
`test_outputabc_success_0.json`

The `output_type` and `folder_type` are strings, whilst the `int` can be any real number (however, in reality won't be larger than 1000.)

I have looked into and implemented things such as `endswith('.json')` and `startswith('test_')`.

I could use `replace()` method to check different parts, which I will do if there is nothing better. I think I can use `isdigit()` as well to check the integer.

I am not very familiar with regex, but expect that could help.

Any ideas on a simple way to verify the entire string which doesn't involve checking these one-by-one? I am happy to create a dictionary or lists which include all possible acceptable sub-strings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex would be the easiest choice:

```
import re
name = "test_outputabc_success_0.json"
result = re.fullmatch(r"test(_[^\W_]+){2}_\d+\.json", name)
if result:
  print("matching!")
```

Regex explanation:

- `test` - starts with `"test"`.
- `(_[^\W_]+){2}` - two occurances (`{2}`) of 1 or more letters `[^\W_]+` not including `_` (underscore), preceding with an underscore. Basically `_word_word`.
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d+` - a sequence of 1 or more digits
- `\.json` - ending with `.json` (the `.` is escaped).

You can even capture the `output_type`, `folder_type` and `int` like so:

```
import re
name = "test_outputabc_success_0.json"
result = re.fullmatch(
  r"test_(?P<output_type>[^\W_]+)_(?P<folder_type>[^\W_]+)_(?P<int>\d+)\.json", name)
if result:
    # Outputs {'output_type': 'outputabc', 'folder_type': 'success', 'int': '0'}
    print(result.groupdict())
```

Regex is extremely powerful!